# Query or a New Column for Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.6, query-performance

I have below tables:
ProductsTable (has product details),
UsersTable (has all application users),
RatingCategry (category for which user can rate a products like Quality, Cost etc.) and
UserRatingsforProductsTable (Users rating for a product for any RatingCategory) for a Mobile Application.

```
Products (ProductId, ProductName… other details like cost etc.)

UsersTable (UserId, UserName… other details like DateOfJoin etc.)

RatingCategory (RatingCategoryId, CategoryName)
**Data:**
1         Quality
2         Cost

UserRatingsforProductsTable (RatingId, UserId, ProductId, RatingCategoryId, Score)
**Data:**
1         5006  20  1   4.5

2         5006  20  2   5.0

3         5600  23  1   3.5

4         7800   20  1   2.5

5         8900   34  1   4.0

6         8900   34  2    4.5
```

What will be the best and faster query for a Mobile Application to show “Rating ScoreTotal” in the Products list (ProductId, ProductName, Cost, RatingScore)? Shall I do calculation in the Query or Add a new column in Products table that will be auto updated when each Rating added into UserRatingsforProductsTable?

```
The expected output should be: 
ProductId, ProductName, Cost, OverallRatingForThisProd
---------  -----------  ----- ------------------------
*** OverAllRating = Average of Ratings from All Categories for the Specific Product from UserRatingsforProductsTable.
```

If the answer will be Query instead of adding a Column, can you please advise an optimized query?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think adding a new column will be efficiently, can you add in your question you expected result?

Comment: I think you are right @oNare. I have added expected result in original question as well. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Nice @Prabhat , I posted 1 query as example of what you could do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think adding a new column will be efficiently and you'll need to do more things like adding `TRIGGERs` to update the field and you'll get the newColumnvalue in every row for the table `UserRatingsForProductsTable`.

**Information:**

```
create Table Products(
  ProductId INT(4),
  ProductName VARCHAR(75),
  Cost DECIMAL(10,2),
PRIMARY KEY (`ProductId`));

CREATE TABLE UserRatingsForProductsTable(
  RatingId int(6) auto_increment,
  UserId int(5),
  ProductId int(4),
  RatingCategoryId int(2),
  Score decimal(5,2),
PRIMARY KEY (`RatingId`));

insert into Products select 20,'Product1',23.33;
insert into Products select 23,'Product2',223.33;
insert into Products select 34,'Product3',323.33;

insert into UserRatingsForProductsTable select 1,5006,20,1,4.5;
insert into UserRatingsForProductsTable select 2,5006,20,2,5.5;
insert into UserRatingsForProductsTable select 3,5600,23,1,3.5;
insert into UserRatingsForProductsTable select 4,7800,20,1,2.5;
insert into UserRatingsForProductsTable select 5,8900,34,1,4.0;
insert into UserRatingsForProductsTable select 6,8900,34,2,4.5;
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    p.ProductId,
    p.ProductName,
    p.Cost,
    ROUND(sum(URPT.Score)/(COUNT(DISTINCT URPT.RatingCategoryId)*COUNT(URPT.UserId)),1) as OverallRatingForThisProd
FROM Products as p
LEFT JOIN UserRatingsForProductsTable AS URPT ON (URPT.ProductId=p.ProductId)
GROUP BY p.ProductId
ORDER BY p.ProductId;
```

Try it on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78d32/5).

Comment: You might want to provide some hints about proper indexes for such query to be executed efficiently.

Comment: Thanks @oNare for this help. I think the calculation for OverallRatingForThisProd will be little different. Please advise.

Please Check this https://www.quora.com/How-should-we-calculating-the-average-from-Multiple-Users-Rated-for-various-Categories

Comment: I have changed the query with your formula, can you try it again?